# How do I specify current target framework in nuspec file?

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

Is there any way to swap the hard-coded *net45* seen below with whatever is specified as the *Target framework* in my project settings?

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\$id$.pdb" target="lib\net45\" />
</files>
```

I was hoping to see something like:

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\$id$.pdb" target="lib\$targetframework$\" />
</files>
```

I don't want my team to have to remember to update the nuspec file whenever the project is upgraded.

It's worth noting that the dll itself makes it's way into the *net45* folder without any extra cajouling.

Cheers

Comment: How you pack you projects? PS script runs nuget.exe and performs the `nuget.exe pack` command? Or `nuget.exe` runs from MSBuild script? Or used MSBuild Pack target?

Comment: I use a Post-build event using nuget pack. Essentially as follows:
`nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -Prop Configuration=$(ConfigurationName)` then
`nuget add $(ProjectName).@(VersionNumber).nupkg -source %PACKAGES_FOLDER%`

Comment: Just try pass `targetframework` parameter as `nuget pack` property, similarly `ConfigurationName`

Comment: Ah... I understand the -Prop option now, but there does not appear to be a macro that produces net45, net451, net461, etc.

Comment: I've now removed my .nuspec file and am trying to include my .pdb files via the AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder setting in the .csproj file.  Thus far I have been unsuccessful.